# How to identify the actual position or line of the exception from the stack trace in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, stack-trace

I'm getting the following stack trace from the users of my Windows Phone 8.1 app,how to identify the actual position or the line of the error?

```
Error Code: -2147024894

Error Message:The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at EM.Backend.LibraryScanner.<ScanLibrary>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at EM.App.<VerifyFirstLaunch>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)
at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good logging strategy should be enough to add more context to unexpected exceptions.

You should be able to analyze your code yourself and find critical code sections where you might feel that, under some circumstances, the code might fail.

Also, the not so-used *[code contracts](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970)* and design by contract pattern can prevent a lot of unexpected issues or easily identify them when they occur.

Sadly, if you don't prepare your code to handle these situations - like your issue with your user -, you'll get into troubles, and you'll need to ask the user for what he/she was doing when the exception was thrown, and try to reproduce the issue step by step.